# How can I make ctrl+cmd+V keyboard shortcut work again in Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, big-sur

Before my upgrade to Big Sur, pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> pasted the current selection with special characters escaped. It's still shown in the menu with this keyboard shortcut.

However, when I press this keyboard shortcut, I get some kind of history popup:
[image: History popup]

Where does this popup come from? I can't seem to find any references to it in the menu. Most importantly: how can I paste the clipboard content escaped into my terminal window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently [Clipy](https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy) uses the same keyboard shortcut for a command. The shortcut can be changed though.

*D'oh!*